# How to set padding (OAEP) for PKCS7_decrypt function using OpenSSL

Tags: swift, encryption, openssl

I'm using OpenSSL to encrypt and decrypt a payload of CMS_envolped data but I want to use the AES256 cipher with OAEP padding (instead of PKCS 1.5 padding). When I encrypt using PKCS1.5 padding I'm fine, and can decrypt, but when I encrypt and use OAEP padding I can't decrypt. How do you set the padding type when decrypting using PKCS7_decrypt?

The [docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/PKCS7_decrypt.html) only talk about a single flag that doesn't apply to padding. Is there a different OpenSSL decryption method I should be using to do my decryption that supports OAEP? I haven't been able to find any docs on it, but I am admittedly not an OpenSSL expert.

```
    guard PKCS7_decrypt(p7, privateKey, x509Cert, decryptedData, 0) == 1 else {
        throw OpenSSLTests.decryptException
    }

    ...
```

This is irrelevant, but I am using OpenSSL in Swift on an iOS client.

Answer (score 3):

Finally found an answer to this.

The docs do not mention OAEP padding anywhere, but it seems that OAEP padding is not supported for the `PKCS7_decrypt` function in OpenSSL. From what I can tell the cipher and the padding are both auto-detected when it tries to decrypt.

I tried using the `CMS_decrypt` function in OpenSSL, which also has no flags to specify padding and it was able to decrypt the `AES256` cipher with OAEP padding just fine.

```
 ... 

    //nil would represent failure
    guard let cms = d2i_CMS_bio(encryptedDataBIO, nil) else {
        throw OpenSSLTestErrors.failedToLoadCMS
    }

   //1 indicates success
    guard CMS_decrypt(cms, key, x509Cert, nil, decryptedData, 0) == 1 else {
        throw OpenSSLTestErrors.failedToDecrypt
    }
```

The docs for CMS_decrypt are located [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/CMS_decrypt.html)

I'd love for a more versed OpenSSL person to explain why the `PKCS7_decrypt` function doesn't work, whereas `CMS_decrypt` does for items encrypted with OAEP padding. (or why does the `PKCS7_decrypt` function succeed with PKCS1.5 padding)

I also don't see where on the CMS_encrypt function on OpenSSL you can specify your padding. By default it uses `PKCS1.5` then I inspect the encrypted data using a decoder. I'm assuming there is a way to set this also, since I was able to decrypt content encrypted using another library that did allow padding to be specified.

Comment: I can confirm this. See my [discussion](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2021-April/013669.html) in OpenSSL user mailing list. By writing simple C programs I was able to prove the problem and find a workaround based on conversion of `PKCS7` struct into `CMS_ContentInfo` struct just before using the `CMS_decrypt()`. I am going to open an issues about this.